Laravel 11: CORS problem even after config/cors.php file setup
Working on a Laravel/React vite project and I'm facing CORS issue, by looking to the laravel docs, it says generating a simple cors.php in the config dir will resolve the issue, but I sill face the problem from my frontend,
Notice that I tried the fruitcake/other package cors php solution but I can't install it due to dependency conflicts.
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => false,

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];


A simple HTTP request using axios in the frontend
    useEffect(() => {
        const getReportList = async () => {
            try {
                setIsLoading(true);
                const response = await API.get('admin/reports');
                setReports(response.data.data);
                setFilteredReports(response.data.data);
                setActiveReport(response.data.data[0]);
            } catch (error) {
                errorManager(error);
            } finally {
                setIsLoading(false);
            }
        }
        getReportList();
    }, [])


My API axios instance snippet
import axios from "axios";
import {
    SERVER_URL
} from "../../constants";

const API = axios.create({
    baseURL: SERVER_URL[
        import.meta.env.VITE_ENVIRONMENT],
    timeout: 12000,
    withCredentials: true
});

API.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
    return config;  //to handle later
});

API.interceptors.response.use(
    function (response) {
        return response;  //to handle later
    },
    function (error) {
        return error; //to handle later
    }
);

export default API;



For Laravel 11, you can disable CORS with a custom made middleware. I did it this way

That's weird, I reexecuted the command php artisan config:publish cors after deleting the config/cors.php and all good

It may sound weird, but basically I just hard refresh the page and deketed the config/cors.php from the backend and re-executed the command
php artisan config:publish cors
and everything was fine!
